# Evaporative cooler, motor issues

Tags: evaporative-cooling

My swamp cooler fan won't turn on. I measured voltage to the motor and if connected it just clicks in the small electrical panel and only sends voltage for a brief second,  the thermostat indicator light turns on only for a brief second.

If I disconnect the motor and measure the high low to ground I get 110 volts  So I assumed  it was the motor.  I purchased a new 1hp dial cooler motor and connected it and  got the same results. I tested the pump and it works fine but the fan motor won't turn.

Any ideas?[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Can you post a photo or diagram to show what you are doing?

Comment: Is there a starting capacitor? A bad starting cap can cause a failure to start.

Comment: Motor is brand new out the box. I actually installed 2 new motors just to make sure I didn't get a bad one out of the box I exchanged it.

Comment: In the picture with the small panel I can hear the contactor switch but it just switches back off a second later

Comment: If I disconnect off the motor and toggle the thermostat from high to low I can measure 115 volts on both line but as soon as I connect to the motor it stops sending power

Comment: My guess is a bad breaker or disconnect.

Comment: It's the same disconnect as my ac unit and the ac unit works fine...I replaced the thermostat control panel and got the same results when I turn on the pump it works but it's very weak. I measured voltage all the way back to the disconnect and it's only running at 70volts. When I turn off the pump it's back to 110 volts...I tested the leg at the breaker and both legs are running at 110...im puzzled